# Google Maps' InfoWindow Automatic Panning Cannot be Disabled

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a button that adds an InfoWindow to a Google Map, but the `disableAutoPan` property seems to be ignored.

```
var map;
function initialiseMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        zoom: 9
    });

    var currentIndicator = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8526, -2.7454),
        content: "Start location"
    });
    map.setCenter(currentIndicator.position);
}

function plotMyLocation() {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.05, -1.25);
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: "My Location",
        disableAutoPan: true
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialiseMap);
```

When the `plotMyLocation` function is invoked, the map always pans to show the position of the newly-added InfoWindow, regardless of the value of the `disableAutoPan` property.

The example at http://jsfiddle.net/H3XLx/ demonstrates the issue.

What am I doing wrong that's preventing disablement of the auto-panning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve it using option list without `map` and calling function `open(map)`:

```
function plotMyLocation() {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.05, -1.25);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: "My Location",
        disableAutoPan: true
    });

    infowindow.open(map);
}
```

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antojurkovic/H3XLx/1/).

From google docs: *Unless auto-pan is disabled, an InfoWindow will pan the map to make itself visible when it is opened. After constructing an InfoWindow, you must call open to display it on the map.*

You provided map property in option list which is not documented.

Comment: Crackin' stuff!  Cheers, mate!